# Rookie build and deployment a dynamic library question

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, dll

I had a request to write a dll library using C#, it should be build under .NET 3.5.
I've build the library (it's a simple TCP client) using Visual Studio 2005 with .NET 2.0.50727.

I'm assuming that I can not deliver this library since it's built against wrong .net 
I have more .NET versions installed on my development machine but it looks like I can't switch the .net in properties like JDK versions in eclipse for a particular project.

Is the only proper way of doing this is installing Visual Studio 2008 Express with 3.5 .NET?
Or some C# sdk with appropriate compiler (the thing is that I don't know the syntax for the c# compiler and NANT would be pain in the ass at this stage)?

cheers
P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3.5 is just 2.0 with additional libraries. Your DLL will work fine from a .Net 3.5 application.

I might be wrong, but I think that 3.5 was introduced with Visual Studio 2008 and cannot be built against with 2005. That's why you can't switch version.

Answer (score 1):

As jgauffin already mentioned your .Net 2.0 assembly will work fine in .Net 3.5.

And switching to another .Net Framework is just downwards possible.

- So with VS2010 you can built against .Net 4, 3.5, 2.0 and 1.1
- With VS2008 you can built against .Net 3.5, 2.0 and 1.1
- With VS2005 you can built only against .Net 2.0
- With VS2003 you can built only against .Net 1.1

So if you really need it just go and download it from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/).

Comment: Actually in VS2005 you cannot select the target framework, and it will always make .NET 2.0 applications. The feature to select the target framework was introduced in VS2008

Comment: @Øyvind Bråthen: Yes, you're right. It's just such a long time ago when i used it. This was one of the *big features* of VS2008, that you could built against different frameworks. So i updated my answer.

Comment: I'll accept jgauffin since he was first and I used already information which he came up with, thought you put additional interesting information. Anyway thanks.